# Extract date that is formatted as mm/dd/yy from cell excel

Tags: excel, date, time

I want to extract a date from a cell but it's formatted as mm/dd/yy so I can't get INT to work. The dates aren't the same length so LEFT or MID wont work correctly for the full data set. I have a sample of the date below. Is there any way to get the date out using a formula as there is roughly 3000 dates?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QVoD.png)

Comment: Why doesn't `INT` work? Have you formatted the cell containing the `INT` formula appropriately?

Comment: Please confirm by whether those are actual excel dates or Textual Dates, since, in excel Dates are stored as numbers so by default numbers are always right aligned, and texts are left aligned, you can confirm this by either pressing CTRL ~ on, which it will show you the dates as numbers and aligned to the left, or you can select the cell and press CTRL 1, and select category Number, it will show you as a number, if this doesnt changes and shows the same as date then its actually a text, kindly confirm this!

Comment: @JosWoolley INT will work for some of the dates. It seems like it works for the ones where the dd in the middle (mm/dd/yyyy) is less than 12. So if the date is 5/7/2021 INT works but if the date is 4/23/2021 it doesn't work. It produces a #VALUE! error.

Comment: What do you mean by "Extract"? A date\time is a Date\time. Excel stores them as numbers.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I've checked the format of the cell that I am trying to get the date from and it is marked as General. I've done this to other data and it's worked when in that format. The main difference that I can see is the other data was in the dd/mm/yyyy format, while this is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @CetinBasoz the original cell has a date and time in it. I want to split the two into separate cells. By extract I just meant copy it to another cell.

Comment: That is just a display format. Underlying data is still a date\time, stored as a number by excel. You should start by explaining the meaning of "extract". ie: If you mean getting this data from outside say using C#, you would simply use an ODBC or OLEDB query. After all it is a datetime value.

Comment: Yes, i have provided you a non dynamic solution, using TEXT TO COLUMNS, please refer below, for the steps, but if you need a formula, it will be different, and one more thing may know, whether you have got this data from any external source or something, just to confirm, only if there is no non printable characters

Comment: @CetinBasoz The original cell is layed out like this [4/23/2021 9:58:32] and I want to be split into two new cells like this [23/4/2021] & [9:58:32]

Comment: @CetinBasoz if that is the case then why is INT not working for ones such as 4/23/21 but does work for ones that are like 5/7/21. The cells are all formatted the same and the formula is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by INT not working or INT working? I didn't say INT but a number in the first place. INT only covers the date part. For splitting as you said, there are two ways: 1) Simply copy there and set formatting to one of date only formats (and time only formats). 2) Use a formula that creates a new date (or time) such as:  =Date(Year(A1), Month(A1), Day(A1))

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya the data is from an external download. I've tried coping and pasting the data as values but I still get the same issue of INT not working for some of the dates.

Comment: @CetinBasoz could you please elaborate more as I don't understand how what you've suggested helps in this case? I can copy the date and time separately for one cell but I have 3000 cells to do this for. I looked into DATE but I'm not sure how to fill it out if the data is already in mm/dd/yyyy instead of each value being in a different cell. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Check my answer, you can either use formulas or change formatting. Once you applied the formula for A1, you simply copy the formula and paste on to those rows in the same column at once.

Comment: @Student when you marked it as General what does it show you, is it showing you numbers or just the same format as copied from external source.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way as well, however this shall not be dynamic and does extracts the Date --> Follow the steps below

1.) Select the range,
2.) From Data Tab --> Goto --> Under Data Tools,
3.) Click Text To Columns,
4.) Step 1 --> Delimited --> Next,
5.) Step 2 --> Uncheck Tab --> Select Space --> Next,
6.) Step 3 --> Data Preview  --> Select The Other Than Date and check Do Not Import Column Skip
7.) Select The Data and from Column Data Format Check Date --> MDY
8.) Finish

STEP1
[image: STEP1]

STEP2
[image: STEP2]

STEP3
[image: STEP3]

OUTPUT EXTRACTED DATES
[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

Date and Datetime in excel are stored as numbers based on an epoch datetime. MM/dd/yyyy, dd/MM/yyyy ... are simply different display formats for the same underlying number.

To split a datetime to date and time values in Excel, there are 2 basic ways:

1. Just copy the same value on to two columns and set only the format to show either just Date or just time (right click, format cells and select your desired date only or time only format).
2. Explicitly create date only and time only values via formulas. ie: Assuming your data starts at A1:

Date only formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

Time only formula:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
```